# SwiftUI - ForEach within a Form doesn't update content, even though it gets stored correctly

Tags: xcode, foreach, view, swiftui, auto-update

I looked everywhere for a solution to my problem, but I couldn't find any. There's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62048265/swiftui-list-not-updating-correctly-with-foreach) that
is similar, but I think I'm having a different problem here. So, my code (Xcode 12.1, developing for iOS 14.0) looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var cm : FolderModel //Which is conformed to Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject
    @ObservedObject var dm : DataManager //Which is conformed to Equatable, Identifiable, ObservableObject
    @State var pressedFolder = false
    @State var valview : ValuesView
    
    
    NavigationView {
        VStack{
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack { ForEach(dm.storageFolders) { foldersForEach in
                    Button(action: {
                        valview = ValuesView(cm: foldersForEach, dm: dm)
                        pressedFolder = true
                    }, label: {
                        Text(foldersForEach.folderName)})
                }
                
                if pressedFolder == false {
                    Form {
                        ForEach(dm.values) { passwordDelForEach in
                            NavigationLink(//This works correctly)
                        }
                    }
                    
                } else if pressedFolder == true {
                    valview //This is the thing that it's not updating when values are added to the folders
                }
                }
                
                

struct ValuesView : View {
                    
                    @ObservedObject var cm : FolderModel //Which is conformed to Codable, Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject
                    @ObservedObject var dm : DataManager //Which is conformed to Equatable, Identifiable, ObservableObject
                    
                    var body : some View {
                        Form {
                            ForEach (cm.folderValues) { folderValuesForEach in
                                NavigationLink(//This works correctly)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The arrays into the DataManager are all declared like this:

```
@Published var storage : [StorageModel] = [] {
   didSet {
      objectWillChange.send()
      }
    }
typealias Storage = [StorageModel]
```

If I add anything into the arrays (from another View), data is stored correctly because by opening the .plist file (that the DataManager creates) I can see it gets correctly updated. Plus, every Button that I use has either the func of the DataManager save() (which has objectWillChange.send() within it) or I manually add dm.objectWillChange.send() to the action of the Button.
Despite all this, the things into the ForEach don't update. I only see the things that were there the first time I open the app, and to see the changes I have to close the app and reopen it.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks to everyone who will answer!

Comment: try this: comment out the NavigationView, and try again

Comment: I just tried commeting out the NavigationView, running the app (and it didn't work), re-putting the NavigationView and running the app again (and it didn't work neither with this...)

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same thing, only as of using the 14.2 simulator. I'm still trying to figure it out, but it seems like views inside of a ForEach are not properly re-rendered on data change.

Comment: Mmm ok, so is there a way to either "remove" the ForEach and "re-put" it so that it gets recalculated, or maybe use something that is not the ForEach but gives me the same result..?